# How to add content to a webpage

Tags: php, html, css

I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to building a website, and I'm trying to teach myself some of the basics. I've set up a webserver on my Raspberry Pi and it works a treat, and now I'm trying to add content to my fairly basic webpage.

At the moment I'm adding the content by directly updating the code of the index.html page using Brackets as my editor. It feels rather longwinded adding content in this way, and I'm guessing there's a way to add the content from a form I can create.

I could go down the route of using a CMS like Wordpress, but I want absolute control over everything on my site. I've written the HTML and CSS myself.

Basically, I'm looking to insert the following into a box on my homepage:

The content I'm wanting to show is a link to an article I've read recently and want to share with others. It'll have the title of the article, a brief synopsis of it, and a small screenshot of it.

In my head it should be a really simple solution, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. It doesn't need to be anything fancy - this is just a little project I'm working on for myself to learn how to build a basic website.

Here's what it currently looks like when I manually enter the content directly into the index.html file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVvX0.png

I want to replicate this, but not have to enter it all directly into the index.html file myself.

Apologies if I'm not making myself clear. I'm having a complete mental block with this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a form on a separate page to post the details via PHP and then get the PHP contents in the actual page.

Add this html to your form page;

```html
<h3>Add Links:</h3>
<p>Enter the details below</p>
<form action="links.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder= "URL:" name="url" required>
<input type="text" placeholder= "Title:" name="title" required>
<input type="text" placeholder= "Added By:" name="name" required style="width: 6.5em;">
<input type="submit">
```

In the `links.php` file you'll need the following.

```
<?php
$url = $_POST["url"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$name = $_POST ["name"];
$timestamp =date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$text = "<a href='{$url}'>{$title}</a> Submitted By: ".strtoupper($name)." on: {$timestamp} <br><br> \n";
$file = fopen("./data/links.html","a+ \n");
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Then add this to your `index.php` page. You'll need the `.php` extension for this to work.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("./data/links.html"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it and it's bringing up a 405 Not Allowed nginx/1.10.3 error. From what I've googled it appears Nginx doesn’t allow accessing static files using POST. Nginx is what I'm using to run by webserver on my Pi.